# Error while installing VirtualBox-4.3

Tags: virtualbox

After installing VirtualBox, I am getting critical error saying "Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object".
Any thoughts ??

Comment: What OS do you have ? Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 32bit

Comment: Try this: Right click on Virtual Box (.exe file) , choose Properties , and select Compatibility tab. There you have an option : Run this program in compatibility mode for windows xp.... Enable this option. Save an run as admin again.

Comment: It should look like this.  http://cdn.computertipsfree.com/wp-content/uploads/how-to-run-program-in-compatibility-mode-in-windows-7-1.jpg

Comment: I'm glad. I will write an answer then , in order not to have this question unanswered .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Start - All Programs , right click on Oracle VM VirtualBox , choose Properties - Compatibility tab . Enable the option : Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows Xp (Service Pack 3) . Run again as admin.